# Auto refresh in PHP

Tags: php, refresh

I have piece of code which refresh data periodically (after 5 sec.), and put it into a table.
This table has sorting option, and checkbox to select a particular row.

Now problem is when i want to sort or choose a row using checkbox, because of auto refresh it set whole table data in previous position. Means if any data i had sorted will not show sorted and/or checked row will be unchecked again.

Please provide me some suggestion how to handle this issue.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Some sample data and code would do an excellent job of helping to explain what you're really trying to do.

Comment: This seems like bad user experience to me.

Comment: Why do you refresh the page every 5 sec, does the table gets populated so fast?

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative might be to do an AJAX call to pull the data periodically instead of refreshing the whole page via PHP. That way you'll be able to send the correct parameters to handle the sort towards the logic within PHP.

OR

You can push named parameters/actions within the url for sorting purposes. Then use URL's on the table header and the page reloads with a url of something like: 
http://example.com/table/sort:asc
http://example.com/table?sort=asc

And then your logic could appropriately pick the previously selected areas up.

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
   //Do sorting stuff
}
```